# Md5 return the raw bytes instead of the hex

Tags: c#, php, md5

I have some PHP code and I want to make it in c#.

My code in PHP :

```
$md5raw = md5($str2hash, true);
```

My code in c# :

```
        static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
    {

        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes 
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string. 
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

the result of this two codes is not identical

PHP:�賞�}��+X�6�
C#:0f9de8b39ee7187d92bb2b5817bb36ee

What should I change in my c# code?

Comment: Do you understand what every line of your C# code is doing? If you don't, that should be your first step. It should then be pretty obvious how to change it.

Comment: i'm new to c# and i haven't used md5 before

Comment: So presumably you just copied this code from somewhere else? *Never* copy code without taking the time to understand what it's doing. Take a step back, learn enough C# (and read enough documentation) so that you can understand the code - then you can change it as and when you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the byte array, skip the conversion:

```
static byte[] GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
{
    return md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You definitively should change your PHP function to return encoded data and use the same encoding in .net (C#).

What you want is to get an string with binary data, but with that you will lose information due to reencoding of the binary data during transfer.

```
static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
{
    // BUG: This code probably will lose information
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
}
```

The way you should do is to use your C# function as in your question and use this as your PHP function:

```
$md5raw = bin2hex(md5($str2hash, true));
```

Comment: now i get e result like this   151572321791582312412514618743882318754238

Comment: `bin2hex(md5($str2hash, true));` is the same as `md5($str2hash);`

Comment: Thank you, your answere worked for me with just a little change. `static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {
            // BUG: This code probably will lose information
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
        }`